# Electron - nucleus collision (relativistic). What is the amount of energy transferred?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, collision

I'm having problem regarding the following case of elastic collision between an electron and a nucleus :

an electron (mass m) hits a nucleus (mass M) which is not at rest in a head-on collision $\theta=0$. I've been trying to calculate the maximum transferred energy to the nucleus by using energy and momentum conservation.

From the energy conservation relation we know that:

$E_1+E_2=E_3+E_4$, where $E_1=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}$ (electron) and $E_2=Mc^2+\frac{Mv^2}{2}$ (nucleus)

and $E_3=\sqrt{p'^2c^2+m^2c^4}$ (electron after ) and $E_4=Mc^2+\frac{Mv'^2}{2}$.

From here you get that $\frac{Mv'^2}{2}-\frac{Mv^2}{2}=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}-\sqrt{p'^2c^2+m^2c^4}$ (1)

I assumed that the $\frac{Mv'^2}{2}-\frac{Mv^2}{2}$=$E_{max}$ (2) is the maximum transferred energy.

From momentum conservation relation you get that:
$p+mv=p'+mv'$. Now I can substitute v' using equation (2) and solve for $p'$, then substitute it in equation (1). However this approach doesn't take me anywhere since I end up with some equation which cannot be algebraicly solved.

I have been reading lately about using the center of momentum frame, which looked promising at first but I don't know how to get to the amount of energy transferred.

Comment: you can find the kimematics of two body scattering here http://www.hep.shef.ac.uk/edaw/PHY206/Site/2012_course_files/phy206rlec6.pdf , paragraph 3

Comment: This looks really promising. I'll give it a try! Thanks

Comment: I've been trying to follow the intstruction but can't get over why is there a sign change from eq. (7) to (9) after substituting $E_1-E_3=\nu$. Why do we get $+\frac{E_1 (E_1-\nu)}{c^2}$ and not $-\frac{E_1 (E_1-\nu)}{c^2}$. Am I missing something out?

Comment: I think he wants to separate the E1 contribution from the E3 contribution by using the substitution into the two terms. I think he is missing a c in the first term of 10